# Java Swing Print - JTextPanel.Print

Tags: java, swing, printing, margin

Well, I don't speak English but I'll try. First I have a problem, I need to print a `Ticket` of a `Company`, my program it's ok but when I try to print, the margins of the printer are `24 25 15 18` or some margins like that. I need to in the print Dialog change the margins to `7 7 0 5`, when I change this margins the result is the best. But my problem is that the program is not for me, it's for a another persons who don't want put the margins in each sale. And I don't know how put the margins as default.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try { 
        this.jTextPane1.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I'm using a `JTextPane` to show a preview and then I print with a code like this :

I know the `awt.Print` but I don't know a lot of this class, and I don't have much time, if you have a new class to print with the margins can be change to default I'll
 grateful with you. Sorry for the English ...

PD: the print is an EPSON-TMU220

Comment: It might be easier to change your JTextPanel to print within the default printer margins.

Comment: *"I don't have much time"*  Hire a consultant.  Voting to close as 'too localized'.

Answer (score 0):

May be this http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html is what you need.

It allows to preview and print paginated `JEditorPane's` content no matter which `EditorKit` is set.